# wxpython, import variable from a frame to another in two different files

Tags: python, variables, wxpython

I have two frames in different files (main frame and settings frame), and I'd like to know if it's possible to pass a variable from a frame in a file to another in the other file. I need it for when I change a value on the settings frame so it can change the main frame actively.

I tried importing them:

main.py:

```
from sett import settingsframe
```

for open the settings frame from the main frame...

sett.py:

```
from main import mainframe
```

but I get an import error (as I thought).

Comment: Are these frames being run in separate main loops? Can one frame be open without the other?

Comment: same loop, the settings frame depends on the main frame to be opened...

Comment: stored the shared parts in a 3rd file and import that into both

Comment: i knew about that, i didn't want to deal with congig/temp files and it will not change the main window actively, i can't handle events from a frame to another neither, is a small app after all, that's the plan b anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both frames belong to the same `wx.App` then I think you can use [PubSub](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxLibPubSub) to send variables back and forth. Unlike `wx.Event` objects, I don't beleive PubSub is tied to parent/child hierarchies. I use PubSub in my application. Although I only have one frame, I do use it to send variables between panels and to/from my database wrapper class.

That link has some example code to get you going so you can see if it will work for you.

Alternatively, since both frames are in the same loop you could do something really hackish like have the frames set each other as a `self` variable. I'd suggest trying PubSub first.

Comment: If you were trying to communicate between two different applications, then that's a different beast all together...